# Can I prevent Github Actions from updating status checks?

Tags: github, github-actions

I have recently started creating Github actions workflows to automate some processes, however one issue I've noticed is that each of the actions creates a new status check on the PRs. This is an issue because I have a few checks I use to limit what PRs should be merged to master (these are tests run through Jenkins that then update the check through the Github API) and these actions checks add clutter and may prevent a PR from advancing if they fail for some reason. I would like the ability to force Github Actions to run quietly and not update the PR's checks, but I haven't been able to find anything. Is there some hidden way to do this?